# SQLiteNetExtension crashes on real device since upgrading to VS 2019

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2019

Since i upgraded my Visual Studio for Mac 2017 to 2019, i can't run my Xamarin.iOS application on my real device.

I use the same database as on the simulator but I always get the exception `OneToMany relationship destination must have Foreign Key to the origin class`

Since i upgraded to VS 2019, I had to change the IOS build settings (linker behaviour: link all | unchecked enable incremental builds).

My code didn't changed but it failed on the first db call on my device.

**Nuget packages:**
 SQLiteNetExtensions 2.1.0 
 sqlite-net-pcl 1.5.231
 sqlitePCLRAW.Core 1.1.13

I will also show my code, but since it's working for more than a year and still working on the simulator, i don't think the mistake is there.

**Repository:**

```
        using (var db = ConnectionHelper.GetConn())
        {
            var resul = db.GetAllWithChildren<CompanyDataModel>().ToList();
            return resul;
        }
```

**Error:** 
*SQLiteNetExtensions.Exceptions.IncorrectRelationshipException has been thrown*

*CompanyDataModel.Functions: OneToMany relationship destination must have Foreign Key to the origin class*

**Classes:**

```
public class CompanyDataModel
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement, Column("ID")]
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ColorType ColorType { get; set; }
    [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
    public List<FunctionDataModel> Functions { get; set; }
    [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
    public List<LocationDataModel> Locations { get; set; }

    public CompanyDataModel()
    {
        Functions = new List<FunctionDataModel>();
        Locations = new List<LocationDataModel>();
    }
}


public class FunctionDataModel
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement, Column("ID")]
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(typeof(CompanyDataModel))]
    public long CompaniesID { get; set; }
    [ManyToOne]
    public CompanyDataModel Company { get; set; }
}

public class LocationDataModel
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement, Column("ID")]
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(typeof(CompanyDataModel))]
    public long CompaniesID { get; set; }
    [ManyToOne]
    public CompanyDataModel Company { get; set; }
}
```